# save figure on multiple folders on matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new on matlab and I don't know many things at the moment.

I have a script which create more than 100 figures. I want to save those figures in 3 different folders. Here is my code until now:

```
pridir='C:\Users\tasos\Desktop\folder';
figtxt1='folder1';
figtxt2='folder2';
figtxt3='folder3';
yM = load('pathtomydata');
[n,m]=size(yM);
maxtau2 = 10;
alpha = 0.05;
zalpha = norminv(1-alpha/2);
p=6;

for i=1:m-1
    for j=i+1:m

        figure()
        y1V=yM(:,i);
        y2V=yM(:,j);
        plot(y1V,'b')
        hold on
        plot(y2V,'r')
        legend(sprintf('text= % d',i),sprintf('text= % d',j))
        title('My Title')
        printto = sprintf('%s%d\\text%d and %d.jpg',pridir,i,i,j);
        print('-djpeg90',printto)
        close(gcf)
    end
end
```

If I left my code like this, all the figures created but they didn't save on folders. If I remove the "%" from the last two lines, I have the following error

```
Error using name (line 103)
Cannot create output file 'C:\Users\tasos\Desktop\folder1\text1 and 2.jpg'

Error in print (line 206)
    pj = name( pj );

Error in test (line 25)
        print('-djpeg90',printto)
```

P.S. I am using the R2012b version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `eval()`!

Define one generic print directory:

```
pridir = 'C:\Users\***\Desktop\fold';
```

Then inside the inner loop:

```
printto = sprintf('%s%d\\figuretext %d and %d.jpg',pridir,i,i,j);
print('-djpeg90',printto)
```

where `printto` will be something like:

```
C:\Users\***\Desktop\fold1\figuretext 1 and 3.jpg
```

Also, you might want to close the figure after the print: `close(gcf)`.

**NOTE:** the directories where you're gonna save the files should already exist, otherwise create them with `mkdir()` before saving any pictures.

Comment: I change all those things but now I have an error
Error using name (line 103)
Cannot create output file 'C:\Users\***\Desktop\fold1\figuretext1 and 2.jpg'

Error in print (line 206)
    pj = name( pj );

Error in test (line 27)
        print('-djpeg90',printto)

Comment: When you defined `pridir` you missed one `\`.

Comment: On the pridir I have a starting and ending quote. It's not this :(

Comment: I meant the backslash \ in  `'C:\Users***\...`

Comment: Oh yes. I added it too but exactly the same error with the \ in the path this time

Comment: Can you paste here again which filename cannot be created? (as per error message)

Comment: Have you created the target directory? Does MATLAB have write permission in that directory? Have you replaced the `***` with your actual username?

Comment: Update my question with the new code. @wakjah how can I see if matlab has write permission in that directory?

Comment: @Tasos Does `folder1` already exists? If not, create it with `mkdir()` before saving any picture.

Comment: That was the problem. I thought that matlab will create them automatically. I will choose your answer as the best. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think matlab changed the code for writing a folder with the 2013 version.

I changed 'XX\YY\ZZ.pjg'
To:
'XX/YY/ZZ.pjg'

And it worked for me, strangely.